# Delphi: Why does this generate a memory leak?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

Why is TDemo.TBuilder is not automatically freed and producing a memory leak ?
TDemo.TBuilder should be freed automatically, as this is a TInterfacedObject object based on IInterface

```
type
  TDemo = class
    public type
      TBuilder = class(TInterfacedObject)
        public
          function Generate: TDemo;
      end;
    public
      class procedure Using;
  end;

implementation

function TDemo.TBuilder.Generate: TDemo;
begin
  Result := TDemo.Create;
  // on finish this method, TDemo.TBuilder should be freed ! 
end;

class procedure TDemo.Using;
begin
  with TDemo.TBuilder.Create.Generate do try
    // use TDemo
    
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: I`m using Delphi XE4

Comment: Because TBuilder.Create returns object reference and reference counting mechanism is not properly initialized.

Comment: You right - TBuilder.Create return TObject but not IInterface :-). How to make TBuilder to automatically destroy after Generate, but use "with" ?

Comment: You are mixing interfaces and classes here. Never do that! A temporary interface variable is mandatory.

Comment: The alternative would be to make `TBuilder` be a `record` instead of a `class` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have memory leak because `TBuilder.Create` returns object reference and since it is used as intermediate reference in with call it was never assigned to interface reference and its reference counting mechanism was never properly initialized.

To solve this, you need to declare `IBuilder` interface and use class function returning that interface for constructing such intermediate object.

```
  TDemo = class
  public type
    IBuilder = interface
      function Generate: TDemo;
    end;

    TBuilder = class(TInterfacedObject, IBuilder)
    public
      function Generate: TDemo;
      class function New: IBuilder;
    end;
  public
    class procedure Using;
  end;


class function TDemo.TBuilder.New: IBuilder;
begin
  Result := TBuilder.Create;
end;

  with TDemo.TBuilder.New.Generate do
  ...
```

Comment: or use generic IBuilder<T: class, constructor> function New: IBuilder; function Generate: T and next TBuilder<T>: class(TInterfacedObject, IBuilder). Thank you very much

Comment: I would suggest making `TBuilder` private (or move it out of `TDemo` completely), and then add a `NewBuilder()` method to `TDemo` to return `IBuilder` rather than using `TBuilder.New()`. This way, users cant create `TBuilder` objects directly.